# How do I configure the ip address with CherryPy?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm using python and CherryPy to create a simple internal website that about 2 people use. I use the built in webserver with CherryPy.quickstart and never messed with the config files. I recently changed machines so I installed the latest Python and cherrypy and when I run the site I can access it from localhost:8080 but not through the IP or the windows machine name. It could be a machine configuration difference or a newer version of CherryPy or Python. Any ideas how I can bind to the correct IP address?

Edit: to make it clear, I currently don't have a config file at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That depends on how you are running the cherrypy init.

If using cherrypy 3.1 syntax, that wold do it:

```
cherrypy.server.socket_host = 'www.machinename.com'
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Of course you can have something more fancy, like subclassing the server class, or using config files. Those uses are covered in [the documentation](https://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/).

But that should be enough. If not just tell us what you are doing and cherrypy version, and I will edit this answer.

Comment: I just needed the first line before my call to cherrypy.quickstart, thanks

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: on "using config files" -- note that `cherrypy.quickstart(application(), config = configfile)` can take an optional config file as the second argument (e.g. in the cherrypy tutorial it is tutconf), which as far as I know will override the cherrypy.server.socket_host set in the program

Answer (score 40):

```
server.socket_host: '0.0.0.0'
```

...would also work. That's IPv4 INADDR_ANY, which means, "listen on all interfaces".

In a config file, the syntax is:

```
[global]
server.socket_host: '0.0.0.0'
```

In code:

```
cherrypy.server.socket_host = '0.0.0.0'
```

Comment: Either. Edited the above to reflect that.

Comment: Why would you ever need to listen on `all` interfaces? Could you explain a bit more here?

Comment: very common in docker containers.

Answer (score 8):

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.server.socket_host = '0.0.0.0' # put it here 
cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```