# cherrypy: cannot connect via IP address or hostname

Tags: python, cherrypy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure the ip address with CherryPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115773/how-do-i-configure-the-ip-address-with-cherrypy)

I am a newbie to cherrypy. I tried out a simple cherrypy app, and I am able to connect via:

```
http://localhost:1111
```

but not via my IP address or host name:

```
http://192.168.1.5:1111 ==> failed
http://myHost:1111      ==> failed
```

That means other people in the network cannot connect to my app. I have been searching the CherryPy document, but not found anything useful. please help.

Comment: Yes, the `server.socket_host='0.0.0.0'` configuration solves my problem. Please post your answer and I accept it. Thank you Burhan.

Comment: Since this is a duplicate of an existing (answered) question, you can answer it yourself and close the question. Or simply delete it, or you can leave it alone and eventually it will be closed.