# How to deploy a CherryPy app locally

Tags: python, webserver, web-deployment, cherrypy

How do I deploy a CherryPy app to my company intranet?

Right now I can access it from my computer with `http://localhost:8080/`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115773/how-do-i-configure-the-ip-address-with-cherrypy) (and many others) with half answer: `cherrypy.server.socket_host = '0.0.0.0'`.

Then what?

What is the URI that allows any computer in the private network to access the app?

Is there any system configuration outside of CherryPy that I need to do? I'm working on Windows 7.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is through SSH tunneling. I'm using `pagekite.py` (http://pagekite.net). It will make your `localhost` port available to anyone in the web.

Comment: I looked at their website, and it looks like it's a service that I need to pay to make my server visible outside my intranet. I need just to see my CherryPy server from the computer of my private network only. Do I need to pay for something that simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the IP of the pc or server you want to serve locally from...

```
cherrypy.server.socket_host = '192.168.0.147'
cherrypy.server.socket_port = 8080
```

Then go into your firewall and allow both inbound and outbound traffic on port 8080 or whatever port you've chosen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a reason why the port should be 8080? In other words, how do I chose a port?

Comment: As long as you're not serving any other sites from IIS or another web server you should be able use port 80.

Comment: No reason at all. Merely historical convention. However, under 1024, some ports are reserved or already bound. By the way, to make it easier, I would bind to 0.0.0.0 so CherryPy would listen on all of your interfaces.